# Can HTMLHint in VS Code be configured to ignore Php and not mark it as an error?

Tags: php, html, validation, visual-studio-code

In VS Code, when using HTMLHint, php tags are flagged as errors (red with wavy underline and listed in Problems pane). Is there a way to make HTMLHint ignore php tags without disabling it completely? Changing the color theme doesn't help.

Comment: Try "spec-char-escape": false in your htmlhint.options.  Does that help?

Comment: Yes, thank you. The opening bracket is still red, but the squiggly lines are gone.